# Determine $ A (t) $ is a function of $ A (0) $.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Bacteria are fed to a population of protozoa at a constant rate of $ \mu $. It is observed that the bacteria are devoured at a rate proportional to the square of their quantity. If $ A (t) $ is the number of bacteria at an instant $ t $, find the differential equation, determine $ A (t) $ as a function of $ A (0) $; What is the equilibrium concentration of the bacteria?

As bacteria are eaten at a rate proportional to the square of their quantity, the differential equation is $ dA / dt = kA ^ 2 (t) $, what I don't understand is how to determine $ A (t) $ in function of $ A (0) $. What occurs to me is to make $ A (0) = u $, and together with the differential equation the solution is $ A (t) = \dfrac {A (0)} {1-kA (0) t} $. And we would have that the equilibrium concentration could not be found. But I don't know if my idea will be okay. Someone would help me.

Comment: $A(t)$ is fine. The equilibrium concentration is the concentration in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

The differential equation governing $A(t)$ is

$ \dfrac{ dA(t)}{dt} = A'(t) = \mu  - k A^2 (t) $

Its solution is by separation of variables

$ \dfrac{ dA}{ \mu - k A^2 } = dt $

Integrating over $[0, t]$, and separating the left hand side using partial fraction expansion,

$ \dfrac{1}{ \mu - k A^2 } = \dfrac{1}{2 \sqrt{\mu}} \left(\dfrac{ 1}{\sqrt{\mu} - \sqrt{k} A} + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\mu} + \sqrt{k} A }  \right)$

Now this intgrates to

$ \dfrac{1}{2 \sqrt{k \mu}} \ln \left( \dfrac{ \sqrt{\mu} + \sqrt{k} A }{ \sqrt{\mu} - \sqrt{k}A }\dfrac{ \sqrt{\mu} - \sqrt{k} A(0) }{ \sqrt{\mu} + \sqrt{k}A(0) }  \right) = t $

For simplicity of analysis, let's assume that $A(0) = 0$, then

$\dfrac{ \sqrt{\mu} + \sqrt{k} A }{ \sqrt{\mu} - \sqrt{k}A } = e^{ \alpha t }$

where $\alpha = \dfrac{1}{2 \sqrt{k \mu}}$

From which,

$A(t) = \sqrt{\dfrac{\mu}{k}} \dfrac{ e^{\alpha t} - 1}{e^{\alpha t} + 1 } $

Hence, as $t \to \infty$ , $A(t) \to \sqrt{\dfrac{ \mu} { k}} $